# Is this safe, or will it only work in English-speaking countries?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, cultureinfo, dayofweek, invariantculture

I've got this code:

```
Calendar cal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
String dow = cal.GetDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now).ToString();
if (dow.Equals("Monday"))
```

...but I wonder if it would still work in German-speaking locales ("Montag") or Spanish-speaking locales ("Lunes"). If not - if looking for "Monday" is problematic - how can I get an int that reprsents day of the week. And even in that case, is 0 always Sunday, or is it sometimes Monday (or even something else)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already an `enum` value, so don't cast it to a `string` before doing the comparison:

```
Calendar cal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
DayOfWeek dow = cal.GetDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now);

if (dow == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{

}
```

Comment: So "DayOfWeek.Monday" is okay? I don't have to worry about DayOfWeek.Montag or DayOfWeek.Lunes or such?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon An enum is a numeric value, not a string - so you don't have to worry about culture when you do the comparison.

Comment: APIs themselves don't get localized in WinRT, so it will always be DayOfWeek.Monday with that semantic, regardless of the current culture setting of the OS. Ultimately, all such details are compiled away and the code is just comparing numbers.